# How to filterBy on a Date type in a p:column

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, primefaces-datatable

i have a problem with filterBy when the data is a date but it works with other types of data,i used a filterFunction which i have already specified in my controller but it doesn't work nothing change when i filter. here is my code:

my .xhtml file:

```
<p:column  filterBy="#{deploiement.date_deploiement_test}" 
           sortBy="#{deploiement.date_deploiement_test}"   headerText="date du déploiement version_test" filterFunction="#{listDeploiementController.filterByDate(value, filter, locale)}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{deploiement.date_deploiement_test}"> 
                                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"  />
                                </h:outputText>
                    </p:column>
```

my controller:

```
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(ListDeploiementController.class.getName());
      
       public boolean filterByDate(Object value, Object filter, Locale locale) {
           
          
           String filterText = (filter == null) ? null : filter.toString().trim();
           if (filterText == null || filterText.isEmpty()) {
               return true;
           }
           if (value == null) {
               return false;
           }
           DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
         

           Date filterDate = (Date) value;
          
           Date dateFrom;
           Date dateTo;
           try {
               String fromPart = filterText.substring(0, filterText.indexOf("-"));
               String toPart = filterText.substring(filterText.indexOf("-") + 1);
               dateFrom = fromPart.isEmpty() ? null : df.parse(fromPart);
               dateTo = toPart.isEmpty() ? null : df.parse(toPart);
           } catch (ParseException pe) {
               LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "unable to parse date: " + filterText, pe);
               return false;
           }

           return (dateFrom == null || filterDate.after(dateFrom)) && (dateTo == null || filterDate.before(dateTo));
       }
```

please if anyone know the solution please show me how i can fix it i really need it for my project.

thank you.

Comment: Post an example of your `filterText`. Also, on what basis you want to decide before/after; is it on the basis of day, month, year, hour and minute only or also on the basis of milliseconds and nanoseconds?

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code:

1. Splitting `filterText` incorrectly.
2. Not realizing the one `Date` object can be before/after another one with a difference of even a millisecond whereas you intended to evaluate before/after only on the basis of day, month, year, hour and minute.

I recommend you do it using the [modern](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) `java.time` date-time API and the corresponding formatting API (package, `java.time.format`) instead of the outdated and error-prone `java.util` date-time API and `SimpleDateFormat`. Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Assuming `filterText` is something like `10-12-2018 17:05 - 05-08-2020 11:25`, I would do it as follows:

```
public static boolean filterByDate(Object value, Object filter, Locale locale) {

    String filterText = (filter == null) ? null : filter.toString().trim();
    if (filterText == null || filterText.isEmpty()) {
        return true;
    }
    if (value == null) {
        return false;
    }

    // Get LocalDateTime from java.util.Date
    Date filterDateValue = (Date) value;
    LocalDateTime filterDate = filterDateValue.toInstant().atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime();

    // Define formatter
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");

    // Split filterText on ' - '
    String[] parts = filterText.split("\\s-\\s");
    String fromPart = parts[0];
    String toPart = parts[1];

    // Parse parts into LocalDateTime instances
    LocalDateTime dateFrom = null;
    LocalDateTime dateTo = null;
    try {
        dateFrom = LocalDateTime.parse(fromPart, formatter);
        dateTo = LocalDateTime.parse(toPart, formatter);
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid dates in the filter criteria");
    }

    return (dateFrom == null || filterDate.isAfter(dateFrom)) && (dateTo == null || filterDate.isBefore(dateFrom));
}
```

Comment: your answer is a good idea it just display the dates 
from smallest to biggest or the opposite,but it doesn't search for a specified date 
That's what i tried to do if you have any idea please show me .

Comment: @YACINEkaneiky - I asked you to post an example of `filterText` but you didn't do that and therefore I assumed that it is something like `10-12-2018 17:05 - 05-08-2020 11:25`. Is this a correct example of `filterText`?

Comment: @YACINEkaneiky - You mean the solution works well for a range but you also need a solution for a specific date. Is it a correct understanding? If yes, what does `filterText` contain for a specific date?

Comment: yes my `filterText` is somthing like `10-12-2018 17:05 `  and yes i need a solution for a specific date like a filterBy do for a number or string

Comment: the `filterText` will search for exemple if we typed `10-` we will have all dates which contain day of number`10` .i hope it was clear.